# Insert a new record for all unique field values in same table?

Tags: postgresql, insert

I have a table, `login.user_tools` with columns, `id`, `userid` and `tool` where `id` is the serialized unique id. there are duplicate records for `userid`.

I know I can get the distinct userids using `SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM login.user_tools`.

How can I INSERT a new record for every unique user id in the table with a new `tool` value?

Comment: Do you need `userid`'s, who repeated only once, insert again into table with  `new tool value`?

Comment: I need to insert a new record for all distinct userids with a new tool value

Comment: and what is new tool value? is that same for every user? if not, how do you generate that ?

Comment: Yes, that will be the same for every user, hard-coded in the INSERT statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Please, before doing insert, make table copy, anyway)

If I correctly understand, you need simply `insert .. select`

```
insert into table_name
(userid , tool)
SELECT userid , 'new_tool_value'  FROM table_name GROUP BY userid
```